# how to install certificate on tomcat ?which is generated on lets encrypt ssl free ssl certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, ssl

I have received certificate.txt which contains 
1)encrypted certificate 
2)private key
3)intermediate certificate 
from the client.i need to install it on tomcat sever which is running on aws 
can any one help me how to move further with this?

Comment: check this url https://helpdesk.ssls.com/hc/en-us/articles/203505171-How-to-install-a-SSL-certificate-on-a-Tomcat-server

Comment: thanks @Satya, but link is showing to import certificate to import certificate into java key file (keystore), but we have not created any keystore file alias name all should be same which is used while generating request file (csr)

Comment: check this as well: https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/tomcat-keytool.htm#ssl_certificate_install